# dictionary of list to list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I was wondering what the best method is to make a function `convert(dict_of_list)` that converts a list of dictionaries to the following:

Before conversion, it is represented as: `{'A': ['A1', 'A2'], 'B': ['B1', 'B2']}`

After conversion, it is represented as: `[{'A': 'A1', 'B': 'B1'}, {'A': 'A2', 'B': 'B2'}]`

I have the following answer, but it feels like it could be done much easier

```
def convert(dict_of_lists):
    if len(dict_of_lists) == 0:
        return []

    keys = dict_of_lists.keys()
    nr_entries = None
    for k in keys:
        if nr_entries == None:
            nr_entries = len(dict_of_lists[k])
        if len(dict_of_lists[k]) != nr_entries:
            return None

    result = []
    for i in range(nr_entries):
        entry = dict()
        for k in keys:
            entry[k] = dict_of_lists[k][i]
        result.append(entry)
    return result
```

Comment: Was there a particular problem when you tried to write such a function?

Comment: Please see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: Could you post your ideas of implementation for convert()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zip`:

```
d = {'A': ['A1', 'A2'], 'B': ['B1', 'B2']}
r = [dict(i) for i in zip(*[[(a, i) for i in b] for a, b in d.items()])]
```

Output:

```
[{'A': 'A1', 'B': 'B1'}, {'A': 'A2', 'B': 'B2'}]
```